# Saving the FolderBrowserDialog Selected Path to database using MySQL and C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Example: Here is my `selected path` from `browserdialog`

```
C:\Users\PHWS13\Desktop
```

After saving it to database, the path goes like this

```
C:UsersPHWS13Desktop
```

My Datatype for the path field is `VARCHAR(100)`

Here is my SQL query

```sql
    CREATE DEFINER=`xxxxxxxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `AddFolder`(folder_loc VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tbl_folder`(`folder_location`) VALUES(folder_loc);
```

How can I fix this?

C# code:

```
public void AddFolder(string f)
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd = new MySqlCommand("call AddFolder('" + f + "')", cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Show the code which calls the proc from C# - that's where the problem will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `\` by using `\\` instead.

Try this at the beginning of your AddFolder method:

```
f=f.Replace("\\","\\\\");
```

Comment: As an aside, you should also look into using Parameters to avoid risk of an SQL Injection vulnerability.  Plenty of info available on Google :)

Comment: Hey can u help me just a simple line of code into using Parameters